# Are sudden traffic spikes from India meant to hurt our AdSense account?

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, malicious

Recently, our page received unusual behavior from visitors in India.
We are receiving spikes of 200/300 real-time users. It lasts for about 30 minutes, then it stops. It repeats several times per day.

Several people warned me, that someone is trying to use fake traffic to destroy our AdSense, but I would like to know is there any other reason for this behavior?

For now, we are dropping all connections from India, but this should not be permanent solution.

Any ideas about this?

Comment: Perhaps you could try a plugin (if it's wordpress) to filter out different things such as this.

Answer (score 1):

AdSense doesn't have the option of blocking specific IPs, otherwise I'd suggest looking into the IPs that are the source of these traffic spikes. You can fill out this form:

https://support.google.com/adsense/contact/invalid_clicks_contact

so that AdSense is aware that this is happening and they may be able to prevent you from being unfairly penalised for fake traffic.

More generally, Cloudflare is good solution for preventing attacks like that. They have free and fairly inexpensive solutions for web security covering click farm and DDos attacks.

Answer (score 0):

First, You can check your campaign details and its information to share. In a campaign, you can mention the country and city where you want to run campaign information correct. Also, check the profile location of your business.

Comment: sorry, i modified my question. Ment to write adsense, not adwords. We do not have any campaigns, but we do receive a lot of fake traffic on our website.
Like someone paid for it